# Related to imagelist

Tags: image

I m working in delphi-2010
i have an imagelist,in which i have added some .png images.
and i have also picture for showing the picture from imagelist.
i want to show the picture on picture box from imagelist.

i wrote the following code,but here addImage(,) takes 2 argument 
one is Values:TCustomImagelist
and another is Index of Image

how i identify the value of customimagelist.

**image1.Picture:=imagelist1.AddImage( , );**

Answer (score 1):

TImageList.AddImage adds a single image from one TImageList to another.  I don't think this is what you intended.

If you want to show one of the images from a TImageList in a TImage, you could use something like this:

```
imageList1.GetBitmap(0, image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```